# Java Bit Shift Left Returns Wrong Value

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, long-integer, shift

I'm having problems with left bit shifts in Java returning incorrect values...

Take 108 << 60 for instance.  The answer should be*:

```
124515522497539473408
```

Java is returning this value

```
-4611686018427387904
```

for this statement:

```
System.out.println(108L << 60L);
```

Why???  Both values are forced longs... so I see no reason why any bit values should be truncated.  What am I missing here?

*Citation: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=108%20%3C%3C%2060)

Comment: Hmm... what's the largest value a `long` can hold?

Comment: I believe it's in the quadrillions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are shifting beyond the length of a `long` (64 bits). 108 occupies seven bits, so `108L << 60L` requires 67 bits to represent it correctly. Actually, since it's a signed type, you'd need 68 bits to avoid having it interpreted as a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

108 is 7 bits, so << 60 is 67 bits number.

Answer (score 1):

The number that represents `108L << 60` is too large to be represented as a `long`.  So you are getting overflow, and losing the high order bits.

If you want to represent numbers this big (without truncation) the simplest was is to use `BigInteger`.

Incidentally, the 2nd operand of a shift operator doesn't need to be a `long`.  The actual shift count is calculated by truncating the operand to a number in the range 0 to 63 (for a `long` shift) - see [JLS 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).